# filter:$viewValue applies not to translation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
<input id="todo" type="text" name="todo_priority" 
 uib-typeahead="priority as priority | translate for priority in vm.priorities 
 | filter:$viewValue" ng-model="vm.todo.priority">
```

The content of vm.priorities is `['low', 'middle', 'high']`.

Unfortunately my filter does not consider my tranlation ( | translate), rather it only considers the content inside vm.priorities. Would be nice if someone knows how to apply the filter on the translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay just developed an on filter method like the following one:

```
vm.translatedMatch = (arrayValue, userInput) => $translate.instant(arrayValue).includes(userInput);
```

and added the following to my template:

```
uib-typeahead="priority as priority | translate for priority in vm.priorities | filter:$viewValue:vm.translatedMatch"
```